# What causes a MongoDB / GridFS MD5 hash mismatch?

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

I'm doing some vetting of MongoDB's GridFS as a binary store and during my tests I have encountered, on rare occasion, an exception being thrown by the driver (in my case, Java) when I validate that the file stored was indeed stored properly. This validation is where the Java driver compares its computed MD5 of the contents it just stored with the MD5 given back by MongoDB's filemd5 command.

This exception is documented and I can work to handle it properly but:

**my question is why does this happen (obviously there is a binary mismatch, but is there anything that causes this to happen more often)?**

I could understand if it occurred during a system failure but it seems to happen seemingly randomly (albeit not very often).

Comment: Can you please provide a specific case? Preferably something that can be reproduced. Along with your driver version and server version for reference.

Comment: Did you confirm that the files do actually differ in this case? If so, what exactly was the difference?

Comment: Unfortunately these happened during an automated build.. I've actually yet to see it when running locally. I'll add more information if I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally had some time to properly look into this, here's what I discovered!

By default, the mongo java driver sets what's known as a NONE/UNACKNOWLEDGED write concern for any and all writes to mongodb. What this means is that writing to mongodb is very much an asynchronous process. The driver says "hey, store all this stuff when you have a chance" and mongo stores it eventually, however a response is returned to the application immediately and so it proceeds with the thread.

Mongo's GridFSFile object of the java driver has a method called `validate` that can be called after having stored a file. This method uses the MD5 that was calculated in memory by the java driver as the stream was divided into chunks and sent to mongodb and it then compares it to the results of a mongo's filemd5 command. When mongo is issued a filemd5 request it takes the provided id and computes an MD5 based on the contents of the various binary array chunks that exist with references to the provided id (which together represent a single entity that was stored in GridFS).

As for what was causing me to see frequent mismatches between the driver's computed MD5 and the MD5 returned from mongo, basically with a default write concern of NONE it was returning control to the application and executing the `validate`/`filemd5` command immediately afterward, which mongo then processes on the current state of it's contents. It's possible (and indeed seems to have been the case) that MongoDB was computing the MD5 for the id before everything had actually been written to memory and so it sometimes returned a bad MD5.

Furthermore, this is consistent with what was seen in debugging details - once the exception occurred I added logging to query the file that was stored and read its contents, and at that point it always had the correct contents and the correct MD5.

The solution is that mongo driver interactions with GridFS must use a write concern of at least ACKNOWLEDGED which means that the data to have been written is at least persisted in memory by mongo before returning to the application. I've set this manually for my tests and enable it for the GridFS collections on app start-up since it's not yet exposed as a configuration option in spring-data. Also worthy of note, is that the new mongo-3.x java driver has a default write concern of ACKNOWLEDGED so once I'm using that I could theoretically remove the extra bootstrapping.

As for why this was never seen locally, it's likely that my machine has the available memory and processing power that mongo requires to store the contents fast enough that by the time the `validate` was called, everything was already there and so the MD5 returned was correct. The build agents running lots of concurrent tests are under significantly heavier load and potentially more limited resources and so mongodb didn't always finish storing the contents before the filemd5 command was executed.

As for validation that this is indeed fixed, I had previously seen 3-4 tests (out of about 2000) fail on every build due to this issue and I have now run over 15 full sets of the tests on the build agents and not seen it once.

The actual code I'm using to correct this:

```
private static final String GRID_FS_FILES_COLLECTION_NAME = "fs.files";
private static final String GRID_FS_CHUNKS_COLLECTION_NAME = "fs.chunks";

@Autowired
protected MongoOperations mongoOperations;

mongoOperations.getCollection(GRID_FS_FILES_COLLECTION_NAME).setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);
mongoOperations.getCollection(GRID_FS_CHUNKS_COLLECTION_NAME).setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);
```

Comment: What version of the Java driver are you using?  The default WriteConcern has been ACKNOWLEDGED since 2.11.0, iirc.

Comment: I don't think the concern is Acknowledged until 3.x +.

Comment: But I was running 2.13 I believe

Comment: If you use the MongoClient class it's ACKNOWLEDGED.  UNACKNOWLEDGED remains the default for the Mongo class.